# Problema al extraer los datos de una entidad debil con llave foranea en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo un pequeño problema al intentar extraer todos los datos de una entidad debíl que tengo creada entre un tabla llamada Doctor y otra paciente. Cuando hago la consulta me extrae los datos correctamente pero por triplicado, es decir, en lugar de devolverme la información de :

```
Juan
Maria
Pedro
```

La consulta me devuelve :

```
Juan
Juan
Juan
Maria
Maria
Maria ...
```

Este es el ultimo intento que e hecho hasta ahora.

```
SELECT * FROM Doctor_Account INNER JOIN Doctor_Patient_Connection ON Doctor_Patient_Connection.PatientAccount_ID=2;
```

Con mi consulta lo que quiero que me devuelva es, todos los datos de cada uno de los doctores que estén vinculados con el paciente.

Comment: Subi la estructura de las tablas por favor para poder guiarte mejor, puede ser que tengas varias relaciones de mas, relaciones con distintos datos por lo que la consulta te trae tres veces lo mismo pero un dato es distinto por lo que a ese dato podrias hacerle un group_concat etc. Segun lo que pones al final si Juan vio a 3 doctores va a salir 3 veces.

Comment: Esta mal hecha la consulta por favor añade tus tablas para poder responder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que añadir un campo común entre las 2 tablas asociadas. Después en el WHERE añadir la condición.  Ejemplo de como debería ser la estructura de la sentencia SQL (datos ficticios):

```
SELECT * FROM Doctor_Account INNER JOIN Doctor_Patient_Connection ON 
Doctor_Patient_Connection.PatientAccount_ID = Doctor_Account.id 
WHERE Doctor_Patient_Connection.PatientAccount_ID = 2;
```

Comment: Y sin la estructura de las tablas como sabes que esos son los campos?

Comment: El campo Doctor_Account.id es ficticio para que se vea la estructura correcta de la sentancia SQL. No obstante, voy a modificar la respuesta.

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias por la respuesta, me ayudo muchísimo a terminar de pulir la consulta la consulta que necesitaba era esta:SELECT * FROM Doctor_Account INNER JOIN Doctor_Patient_Connection ON 
Doctor_Patient_Connection.DoctorAccount_ID  = Doctor_Account.DoctorAccount_ID 
WHERE Doctor_Patient_Connection.PatientAccount_ID = 2;